# Replacing PDF text using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I wanted to create invoice pdf's with a pdf template. It requires to replace 10 or more texts inside the pdf. 
PDFBox doesn't seems to be supporting direct text replacing.
Is there a way to do this with PDFBOX? (found one token replace method but seems to be taking much processing to do the small task)

Comment: Replacing text in pdfs is no *small task*, at least as long as the pdfs cannot be counted on internally being structured in a very special way.

Comment: Your whole strategy is a weird one. If you want templates, use acroform read only fields, this could work for things like address, invoice# but not for variable data, i.e. the items purchased. For the variable data you'll need to write the tables and the contents the hard way at the correct place. (or use boxable). Alternatively, have a look at Apache FOP.

Comment: its an invoice, since I dont want to create from the scratch thought to use the already existing PDF and change the important data (This also include table data)

Answer (score 0):

PDFBox had the replace text functionality but was removed (https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#why-was-the-replacetext-example-removed), I would use Jaspersoft Studio (http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) instead, it's easy to use.

Jaspersoft Studio does not operate on a "pdf template", but on JasperReports templates. Those then may be exported to PDF.

Comment: Jaspersoft Studio does not operate on a "pdf template" as the OP wants but on JasperReports templates. Those then may be exported to PDF but that still is very different from what the OP asked for.

Comment: @mkl: correct, which is still doable and easier than having a PDF template, added your clarification